# Como alterar uma lista de outro ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf

Desenvolvi uma área de busca no meu sistema onde o usuário pode adicionar um item na sua lista de itens. Como um carrinho de compras.

A área de busca utiliza um ManagedBean diferente a do painel do usuário que tem um dataTable que é carregado em outro managedBean.

**O que eu quero:** Já estou persistindo o item corretamente, porém eu uso no painel de usuário SessionScoped e queria que a lista do dataTable atualizasse o novo item imediatamente.

Da maneira que está agora eu tenho que fazer um logout do usuário e logar novamente para o item carregar.
Eu não posso alterar para viewScoped, pois tenho outros componentes (dialog e confirmDialog) na página que precisam de dados na memória.

Bean para página de Busca com método que cadastra um novo item:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "api")
@SessionScoped
public class AplicacaoBean implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Pega o usuário logado
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{uBean.usuario}")
private Usuario usuario;

//Outros atributos e métodos

public String acompanharCaso() {
    Patrulheiro patrul = new Patrulheiro();
    if (usuario.getEmailAddress() != null
            && usuario.getEmailAddress() != "") {

        try {
            patrul = (Patrulheiro) buscarPatrulheiroPorEmail();
            assocLocaliza = new PatrulDesapLocaliza();

            assocLocaliza.setDesaparecido(desaparecido);
            assocLocaliza.setPatrulheiro(patrul);
            List<PatrulDesapLocaliza> acompanhamentos = Arrays
                    .asList(assocLocaliza);
            patrul.setPatrulLocalizaDesap(acompanhamentos);

            new PatrulheiroJPA().gravarAtualizar(patrul);
            FacesUtil
                    .addSuccessMessageWithDetail("frmDialogo",
                            "Dados enviados",
                            "Agora você está acompanhando esse caso! Verifique no painel de usuário");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Não é um Patrulheiro
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessageWithDetail("frmDialogo", "Atenção",
                    "Você deve ser um Patrulheiro para acompanhar o caso!");
        }

    } else {
        // Nao está logado
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessageWithDetail("frmDialogo", "Atenção",
                "Logue-se como Patrulheiro para acompanhar o caso!");
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Bean para página do Usuário com a lista que deveria receber o novo item:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "patrulBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PatrulheiroBean implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  // Pega o usuário logado
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{uBean.usuario}")
  private Usuario usuario;

  //Outros métodos e atributos

  @PostConstruct
  public void inicializar() {
      try {
          limpar();
          //lista que deve receber o novo desaparecido adicionado
          listaDesaparecido = new DesaparecidoJPA()
                  .buscarDesaparecidosPorIdPatrulheiro(usuario);

      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Não foi possível resgatar os dados da lista de acompanhados");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public void limpar() {
      desaparecido = new Desaparecido();
      descricao = new DescricaoDesaparecido();
      patrulheiro = new Patrulheiro();
      assocLocaliza = new PatrulDesapLocaliza();
  }
}
```

Teria como eu carregar e alterar essa lista do painel de usuário em outro bean, Ou quando o usuário entrar no seu painel a lista ser atualizada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema, depois de tentar usar `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{patrulBean}")` que me causou os erros nos comentários.

Utilizei a tag do `f:event` com o tipo `preRenderView` e fiz a chamada para o método que carrega a lista toda vez que a página é chamada:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/Layout.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{patrulBean.iniciarLista}" />
</f:metadata>
...
```

Mais: [JSF 2 PreRenderViewEvent example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/)

Valeu pela ajuda também Nilson

Answer (score 1):

Inclua o ManagedBean como uma property e atualize a coleção dele.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "api")
@SessionScoped
public class AplicacaoBean implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{uBean.usuario}")
private Usuario usuario;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{patrulBean}")
private PatrulheiroBean patrulheiroBean;

public String acompanharCaso() {
    //...
    patrulheiroBean.atualizaColecao();
}
```

Comment: Legal, assim funciona, porém surgiu outro erro. Quando eu faço o primeiro login com o Patrulheiro ocorre o NullPointer: `FATAL: JSF1073: java.lang.NullPointerException obtido durante o processamento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=null
nov 25, 2015 12:00:01 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
FATAL: No associated message
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.com.aenc.entity.Usuario.hashCode(Usuario.java:126)`. Mas se eu logar novamente aí não ocorre o erro.

Comment: Na linha dessa classe Usuário está assim: `@Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + id; //Linha com erro
  return result;
 }`

Comment: Esse erro está relacionado ao property `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{uBean.usuario}")  private Usuario usuario;` que já existia no seu código antes de eu propor a alteração. Nesse caso vc terá que ver na sua lógica o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Pois é, parece que se eu usar dois managerProperties ocorre esse erro em um Bean, pois no PatrulheiroBean eu também carrego a mesma propriedade "#{uBean.usuario}" para pegar dados do usuário.

Comment: Não, eu tenho MBs em que eu uso 4 managedProperties sem problemas.

Comment: Consegui achar a causa, mas não a solução:
 Esse bean `api` é o meu index e é referenciado primeiro na execução, quando tento realizar o login do `patrulheiro` ocorre o NullPointer porque o seu objeto já foi referenciado e estava nulo. Se eu rodar a página de login direto o erro não ocorre. Tentei **apagar** a propriedade `uBean` de `api` e usar a partir da propriedade `patrulBean.usuario.nome`, mas ocorre o mesmo erro.